# How to filter rows in Pandas based on specific value in 1 column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv, like this (no headers):

```
a1   b1  3
a2   b2  5 
a3   b3  8
```

I want to get all rows, where values in last column is `>4`. How can I do that?

P.S. This is why this is not duplicated question - in the link above columns are named, my columns are unnamed.

Comment: @jezrael explain please how can I use that answer in my case? I have already seen it but did not get how to use it in my case - in that case columns are named, my columns are unnamed.

Comment: Sorry, reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select last column:

```
df = df[df.iloc[:, -1] > 4]
print (df)
    0   1  2
1  a2  b2  5
2  a3  b3  8
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.iloc[:, -1])
0    3
1    5
2    8
Name: 2, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I have already tried something smilar, but I get this error - `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

Comment: But wait now. If he pass header=False then it will be df[2]. I think OP might have missed that. There are no dfs without columns.

Comment: @Chiefir - Waht return `df.iloc[:, -1]` ? there are numbers? If yes, how working `df.iloc[:, -1].astype(int)` ?

Comment: @Chiefir - Because maybe numbers saved as strings.

Comment: @jezrael you were right - the column was a string, not int.